# How to disable ribbon keytips?

Tags: microsoft-office, ribbon

Since Microsoft Office 2007, ribbon toolbar has been added. When I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, ribbon keytips will show.

[image]

How can I **disable keytips** showing? So that when I press <kbd>Alt</kbd> key, I want nothing to happen, because I find it very annoying when I switch keyboard layouts with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>and sometimes keytips will show.

Comment: Have you tried changing the shortcut for keytips to the `ctrl` button  on those systems with the other layout?

Comment: @Ramhound: How can I change the shortcut for keytips? And what is the purpose of it? I want to disable keytips shortcut, not change it to `ctrl`.

Comment: yes, this is extremely terrible UX from Microsoft, it makes typing SO hard. Whoever invented this, doesn't know his users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a "baked in" feature. It's called a [UI affordance](http://www.usabilityfirst.com/glossary/affordance/) as it's meant to highlight that the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key will trigger those actions.

Comment: Do you know it or do you just "believe" that I cannot disable it?

Comment: Well it's very hard to prove a negative. I can't find an option to disable. And 20 years of writing software makes me doubt that they would offer one.

Comment: Ok, its very strange that such an option to disable it does not exist - but thank you for the answer.

Comment: Office moderator says "Just ignore the keytips and continue to enter your shortcut" - https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-word/how-do-i-turn-off-keytipsalt-functions-the-ribbon/2bced1b9-5b73-4736-8a37-35fb9b34dfe8

Answer (score 6):

I have a partial fix for this.  To disable the KeyTips when only pressing Alt apply the following registry change:

Word 2013

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\word\disabledshortcutkeyslist]
"KeyMod1"="18,16"
```

Word 2016

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\word\disabledshortcutkeyslist]
"KeyMod1"="18,16"
```

The KeyTips will still appear after using a built-in Alt shortcut but at least it is progress.

Comment: source: "Disabling shortcut keys by using virtual key codes / control IDs / Group Policy" - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-2013-resource-kit/cc179143(v=office.15)

Comment: Note that this also disables the actual keyboard shortcuts, i.e. you can no longer navigate the Word menus using the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

We all gave up moments before hitting the gold.
To ultimately disable the ribbon when switching language with shift+tab, you need to insert this into cmd:

```
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\word\disabledshortcutkey list /v KeyMod1 /t REG_SZ /d 18,4,16
```

or create a .reg file with

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\word\disabledshortcutkeyslist]
"KeyMod1"="18,4,16"
```

This works as of February 9th, 2024.
The decade long question has finally found its' answer.
We may rest now, my brothers and sisters.